# Вопрос о конструкторе Java

Tags: java

Есть `package` `p1`, в котором расположены 3 файла:

`Demo.java`:

```
package p1;

public class Demo 
{
    public static void main(String [] args)
    {
        Protection ob1 = new Protection();
        
        Derived ob2 = new Derived();
    }
}
```

`Protection.java`:

```
package p1;

public class Protection 
{
    int n = 1;
    private int n_pri = 2;
    protected int n_pro = 3;
    public int n_pub = 4;
    
    public Protection()
    {
        System.out.println("Konstruktor bazovoo klassa.");
        System.out.println("n = " + n);
        System.out.println("n_pri = " + n_pri);
        System.out.println("n_pro = " + n_pro);
        System.out.println("n_pub = " + n_pub);
    }
}
```

`Derived.java`:

```
package p1;

public class Derived extends Protection
{
    Derived()
    {
        System.out.println(12);
    }
}
```

Вывод:

> Konstruktor bazovoo klassa.
>
> n = 1
>
> n_pri = 2
>
> n_pro = 3
>
> n_pub = 4
>
> Konstruktor bazovoo klassa.
>
> n = 1
>
> n_pri = 2
>
> n_pro = 3
>
> n_pub = 4
>
> 12

Почему срабатывает 2 раза конструктор класса `Protection`, если я его не вызывал в классе `Derived`, например, `Derived() {super()};` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

При срабатывании конструктора потомка всегда вызывается конструктор предка, даже если вы не вызываете его явно. Компилятор сам дописывает вот такую строчку за вас:

```
 Derived()
     {
        super(); // autogenerated
        System.out.println(12);
     }
```

Причем вызов коструктора супер класса всегда идет первым ! (таковы правила). Если вы попробуете изменить порядок, то компилятор сообщит вам об ошибке.

Answer (score 2):

Потому что он вызывается неявно